# Calculating Word Frequency Using StreamTokenizer () , HashMap() , HashSet(). in Java Core

Tags: java, hashmap, tokenize, hashset

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Console con = System.console();
        String str;
        int i=0;
  
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        HashSet set = new HashSet();
 
        System.out.println("Enter File Name : ");
        str = con.readLine();
        File f = new File(str);
        f.createNewFile();
        
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(str);
        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(fis);
        while(st.nextToken()!=StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
         String s;
    
         switch(st.ttype) {
             case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:  s = st.nval+"";
             break;
              case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:    s = st.sval;
               break;
                default: s = ""+((char)st.ttype);
            }


            map.put(i+"",s);
            set.add(s);
            i++;
        }
 
        Iterator iter = set.iterator();
        System.out.println("Frequency Of Words :");
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
          String word;
          int count=0;
          word=(String)iter.next();
          
            for(int j=0; j<i ; j++) {
             String word2;
              word2=(String)map.get(j+"");
               if(word.equals(word2))
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(" WORD : "+ word+" = "+count);
        }
        System.out.println("Total Words In Files: "+i);
    }
}
```

> In This code First I have already created a text file  which contains the following data :

**@ Hello Hii World #  * c++ java salesforce**

> And the output of this code is :

**Frequency Of Words :

WORD : # = 1

WORD : @ = 1

WORD : c = 1

WORD : salesforce = 1

WORD : * = 1

WORD : Hii = 1

WORD : + = 2

WORD : java = 1

WORD : World = 1

WORD : Hello = 1

Total Words In Files: 11**

> where i am unable to find why this shows c++ as a seperate words . I
> want to combine c++ as a single word as in the output

Comment: What is your definition of "word"?

Comment: @ Sweeper words means  strings present in the txt files

Comment: Yes, but what constitutes _one_ word? Why is `c++` a word? Should `word$$$$` be one word or two words or 5 words? How do I know what is a "word"?

Comment: @sweeper word$$$$ constitutes a singles word

Comment: @sweeper help me sir

Comment: Didn't you say that if you use `StringTokenizer` it works?  So do you mean words are separated by spaces? `xxx.xxx xxx` would be two words?

Comment: @ sweeper yes sir it shows xxx.xxx and xxx are two different words.  But as in the same way I want to do with the streamTokenizer

Comment: @sweeper tell me what wrong in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way

```
    // Create the file at path specified in the String str
    // ...
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(str);
    Reader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(bufferedReader);
    st.wordChars('+', '+');
    while(st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
        String s;

        switch(st.ttype) {
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                s = String.valueOf(st.nval);
                break;
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                s = st.sval;
                break;
            default:
                s = String.valueOf((char)st.ttype);
        }
        Integer val = map.get(s);
        if(val == null)
            val = 1;
        else
            val++;
        map.put(s, val);
    }

    Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
    Iterator<String> iter = keySet.iterator();
    System.out.println("Frequency Of Words :");
    int sum = 0;
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        String word = iter.next();
        int count = map.get(word);
        sum += count;
        System.out.println(" WORD : " + word + " = " + count);
    }
    System.out.println("Total Words In Files: " + sum);
```

Note that I've updated your code using Generics instead of the raw version of HashMap and Iterator. Moreover, the constructor you used for StreamTokenizer was deprecated. The use of both map and set was useless because you can iterate over the key set of the map using .keySet() method. The map now goes from String (the word) to Integer (the number of word count).

Anyway, regarding the example you did, I think that a simple split method would have been more appropriate.

For further information about the wordChars method of StreamTokenizer you can give a look at [#wordChars(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#wordChars(int,%20int))

Comment: Integer is the wrapping class of the int primitive type and it is used for storing the number of each word repetition.

Comment: Sir when I try to solve with primitive int data type so at run time compiler shows the classcasteException..  So is it not possible with int datatype

Comment: You cannot use int instead of Integer as for the hashmap. If you want to use int instead of Integer as for the "val" variable, you should do in the following way
`int val = 1;
if(map.get(s) != null))
    val = map.get(s) + 1;
map.put(s, val);`
but there aren't advantages using this solution because there is the autoboxing of the int value. Moreover, note that you cannot compare int primitive type and null.